# Adding commas to database requests

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this as part of a line of code in my php file:

```
($install["eco_plus"] ? "Eco+ " : "") . ($install["satnav"] ? str_replace('_', ' ', $install["satnav"]) . " " : "") . ($install["ttConnect"] ? "TTConnect " : "") . ($install["fms"] ? "FMS " : "") . ($install["remote_link"] ? "Remote Link " : "") . ($install["remote_logbook"] ? "Remote Logbook " : "")
```

It outputs this into my table:

```
Eco+ Go 530 TTConnect FMS Remote Link Remote Logbook
```

I want it to output something like the following:

```
Eco+, Go 530, TTConnect, FMS, Remote Link, Remote Logbook
```

I'm unsure of how to do this without having it output something like this:

```
Eco+, Go 530, TTConnect, FMS, Remote Link, Remote Logbook,
```

or When its not displaying all of the data and only part like this:

```
Eco+, Go 530,
```

I would appreciate any help you can offer or link me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each item into an array, and use `implode()`:

```
$array = array();
if ($install["eco_plus"]) {
    $array[] = "Eco+";
}
if ($install['satnav']) {
    $array[] = str_replace('_', ' ', $install["satnav"]);
}
if ($install['ttConnect']) {
    $array[] = 'TTConnect';
}
if ($install['fms']) {
    $array[] = "FMS";
}
...
$features = implode(', ', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comma to all your substrings and remove the last one with [rtrim function](http://php.net/rtrim) :

```
rtrim(($install["eco_plus"] ? "Eco+, " : "") . ($install["satnav"] ? str_replace('_', ' ', $install["satnav"]) . ", " : "") . ($install["ttConnect"] ? "TTConnect, " : "") . ($install["fms"] ? "FMS, " : "") . ($install["remote_link"] ? "Remote Link, " : "") . ($install["remote_logbook"] ? "Remote Logbook " : ""),",")
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work but Barmar answered first :)

Comment: @user3110168 Barmar answered better, but not first! :-)

Comment: His answer was the second to appear on my screen and in my notifications, behind the one guy who told me my post was in-comprehensive.